# gnuplot line graph plotting irregular x-axis values with fixed interval

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following excel data and corresponding line chart
[image]

I wanted to plot it using gnuplot script

```
set term postscript eps enhanced monochrome     
set output "r-all-float-case4.eps"          
set size 1.0,1.0                    
set pointsize 1.75                  
set xlabel "X-values" font "Times-Roman,24"         
set title "Irregular intervals"
set  key ins vert left top
set key spacing 1.5
set key font ",14"
set size 1.0,1.0             
set ylabel "time" font "Times-Roman,24" 
set log y
plot \
"mydata" using 1:2 title "Y1" with lp lt 1 lw 3 , \
"mydata" using 1:3 title "Y2" with  lp lt 2 lw 3
```

and it gave me the following output

[image]

How can I make the x-axis look the same like the excel one (data points with fixed interval)?

Comment: I'm afraid this is off-topic on the site. [so] has a [`gnuplot`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gnuplot) tag with more than 2500 questions.

Comment: From the discussion in chat: a question on how to use `gnuplot` with TeX or related software would be on-topic, but this is purely a `gnuplot` question